# How to sort data in document

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents.
When I run this code

```
mydoc = mycol.find({ "orders.lineItems.price": { "$gte": 1.0 } },{ "_id": 0, "orders.lineItems.price": 1 }).sort("orders.lineItems.price").limit(1)

for x in mydoc:
    print(x)
```

I get this:

```
{
   'orders':[
      {
         'lineItems':[
            {
               'price':80.38
            },
            {
               'price':2.72
            },
            {
               'price':55.77
            },
            {
               'price':74.9
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         'lineItems':[
            {
               'price':76.01
            },
            {
               'price':5.63
            },
            {
               'price':84.59
            },
            {
               'price':65.29
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see in the code above
I tried using sort function
but it did not sort he price

For each 'lineItems' I need:

To sort the prices from lowest to highest

To sum the prices to a total number.

Please help me to find a solution.

Noam.

Answer (score 0):

If you could make your list a little more readable and make it a list of list:

(i assume, your dict is declared 'price_dict')

```py
def convert_price_dict_to_list(price_dict):
    orders = []
    price_dict = [order['lineItems'] for order in price_dict['orders']]
    for order in price_dict:
        orders.append([item['price'] for item in order])
    return orders

orders = convert_price_dict_to_list(price_dict)
# [[80.38, 2.72, 55.77, 74.9], [76.01, 5.63, 84.59, 65.29]]

print([sorted(order) for order in orders])
# [[2.72, 55.77, 74.9, 80.38], [5.63, 65.29, 76.01, 84.59]]
```

If you really don't want to change to list of lists, you can use the following function to return th dict of lists of dict of lists of dict in your format:
(as far i can read it, its correct)

```py
def sorted_price_dict(price_dict):
    sorted_dict = {'orders': []}
    for order in price_dict['orders']:
        sorted_dict['orders'].append({'lineItems': sorted([price for price in order['lineItems']])})

sorted_price_dict(price_dict)
# {'orders': [{'lineItems': [{'price': 2.72}, {'price': 55.77}, {'price': 74.9}, {'price': 80.38}]}, {'lineItems': [{'price': 5.63}, {'price': 65.29}, {'price': 76.01}, {'price': 84.59}]}]}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually, I have no idea how to convert the result I got into a list.

Comment: Hi, This is not a regular dict or list since MongoDB. This is the error I get: `pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot set options after executing query`. Since this is MongoDB, I imported pymongo so "mydoc" is MongoDB document.

Comment: afaik you can try to convert it like >>> import json
>>> mydoc = json.loads(mydoc)